# Python extract query string from multiple files and put into new file

Tags: python, file-io

I have multiple files of text in a format like this (see below) and I want to extract >TAIR:175 and the string of characters underneath it from each one.  Then I want to put each >TAIR:175 + characters together in a new file:

ex:

File 1:

```
>TAIR:175 a
 ALSKDJFLKAHGLKASJDFLAKJSDLKGHALKSDHGALKALKSJDF
>TAIR:674 a
 ASLALKSDGHLA;KSJDFIEURALKSDHGLANVAL;KSDJGHKLJA
>TAIR:812 a
 KLJALSKDHGLAKSDHJFIEUROWASDLKGNIEASDFJKWERLJKJ
```

File 2:

```
>TAIR:975 b
 KLJALSKDHGLAKSDHJFIEUROWASDLKGNIEASDFJKWERLJKJ
>TAIR:175 b
 ZZZLAALSKDJFALKSDJFL;KJEIURALKDJFNVALKSDJFKZZZ
>TAIR:444 b
 QQALKSDJFWOIAOQIWUERTOIUQTOIUOQIWEURLASKDJFA;KL
```

New File:

```
>TAIR:175 a
 ALSKDJFLKAHGLKASJDFLAKJSDLKGHALKSDHGALKALKSJDF
>TAIR:175 b
 ZZZLAALSKDJFALKSDJFL;KJEIURALKDJFNVALKSDJFKZZZ
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('3.txt', 'w') as f_out:  # open result file
    for fn in ('1.txt', '2.txt'):  # iterate through multiple files
        with open(fn, 'r') as f_in:
            for line in f_in:
                if line.startswith('>TAIR:175 '):
                    f_out.write(line)
                    f_out.write(f_in.readline())
```